# XML parsing with KSoap 2 Library

Tags: android, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I have no experience with soap XML parsing. So Please any one suggest me how to get this response using K soap2 library

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="LEADID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MobileNO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="CustName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="EmailID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Mobile_x0020_No" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Lead_x0020_Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Channel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Product" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="LeadCreatedOn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Branch" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="CustType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"/>
</DataSet>
```